# Make the bootstrap table scroll-able vertically and horizontally with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

How to make bootstrap table scroll-able vertically and horizontally with fixed header?

I got one solution but there are some **limitations** like:

- The width of th and td will be fixed
- The height of the table will be fixed

That solution is here:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/)

I'm trying to make the table with these properties:

- Responsiveness(Height and width)
- Dynamic width of td and th
- Vertical and horizontal scroll-able with fixed 'thead'

With bootstrap table, i have done this...

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 350px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1%;
}

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="">
    <table class="table-fixed table table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
          <th>Example</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Multiple rows and columns to make it scroll-able.
In this table,

- The width of td and th in the same column are same.
- The width of of different columns are not fixed.
- The table is responsive.

The only problem with this table is, the **header is not fixed**.
I tried things that i have mentioned in my previous post. [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217171/horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-able-table-in-bootstrap)

How to make the "thead" fixed of this bootstrap table with vertical and horizontal scroll-bar?

Answer (score 5):

put the table inside the div like code below to make scrollable table.

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;"> 
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to do this with display: block.

Something like this:

```
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}
table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
}
```

[See the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7UZA4/1385/)

Comment: Have you visited those inks which i mentioned in my post?

Comment: Yes, check this updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/or4kzuaf/1/). I used your code in this link.

Comment: The table with "tbody width:100%" is not a solution. Requirement is to make it scroll-able vertically and horizontally, please go through my question once again. 
And if i make the table in bootstrap grid, say half of the screen then it should take only half and should be horizontally scroll-able. But in your solution, it is not happening.. http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/2/

Comment: I just copy his cody and add `thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}`.
I update the code now to show the horizontal scroll bar, [look](http://jsfiddle.net/or4kzuaf/10/)

Comment: The solution is not correct. Check this.. [Your Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/11/) when we need 2 tables in a row...
Now check this one... [My Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/5/), in my solution, the only thing remaining to make the width of 'td' and 'th' dynamic, not fixed. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Finally i got the solution... [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/16/)

Comment: Ok, I understand what you did.

Comment: but if I want to add Horizontal Scrollbar only to the last two columns. Last two columns should be wrapped in a scrollable container. How can we implement this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114303/how-to-add-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-react-bootstrap-table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
thead {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
td, th {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100px;

}
.container{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <table class="table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Example</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Female</td>
          <td>Yes</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This table is not horizontally scroll-able, and i want to remove the limitation of fixed width of td and th.. I don't want like this http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/4/.
Please, see my requirements once more...

Comment: This is a [SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/5/), but problem is: **fixed width of all columns**.
I'm trying to give dynamic width to the column items, if width of "td" is more than "th", then this should be the width of the whole column and same for the opposite case.

Comment: Finally i got the solution... [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/or4kzuaf/16/)

Comment: It seems it doesn't matches with your requirement...how ever the column width and heading width is not equal right?

Comment: pretty nice...but still i'm finiding the way to dynamically set the columns width. Anyway thanks for you to making me to think a lot!!!